# Not able to set focus on input field after jQuery UI select event

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI tabs to switch between some forms.
Now I need to add `focus()` on the first input field when a tab is clicked.

If I click the tab with index 2, the alert is fired but the `focus()` is not.

```
  jQuery("#newRegistration").tabs({
    fx: { opacity: 'toggle', speed: 'fast' },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      if(ui.index == 0) { jQuery('#form1_name').focus(); }
      if(ui.index == 1) { jQuery('#form2_name').focus(); }
      if(ui.index == 2) { alert('this shows'); jQuery('#form3_name').focus(); }
    }
  });
```

Why is the focus not working?

The form data looks like this (short version):

```
<div id="registrationforms">
  <form id="form1_data_form" class="ui-tabs-hide" action="" method="post"></form>
  <form id="form2_data_form" class="ui-tabs-hide" action="" method="post"></form>

  <form id="form3_data_form" class="" action="http://mysite.com/register/" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="40" name="form3_name" id="form3_name">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `show` event instead of the `select` event.

```
jQuery("#newRegistration").tabs({
    fx: { opacity: 'toggle', speed: 'fast' },
    show: function(event, ui) {
      if(ui.index == 0) { jQuery('#form1_name').focus(); }
      if(ui.index == 1) { jQuery('#form2_name').focus(); }
      if(ui.index == 2) { alert('this shows'); jQuery('#form3_name').focus(); }
    }
});
```

Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/HN9uK/.